# Почему разваливается адаптив?

Tags: html, адаптивная-верстка

Сайт : [http://окнавтуле.рф](http://%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5.%D1%80%D1%84)

При просмотре с телефона или через консоль в хроме, сайт выглядит нормально (версия для смартфонов)

При просмотре с других браузеров, например firefox сайт будто приближен.

Пробовал менять viewport, минимальная ширина body установлена но от изменения толку нет.

Что я проглядел?

Comment: попробуйте вьюпорт вот так записать: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: В таком случае разваливается и в хроме

Comment: Необходимо вставить ваш код в вопрос.

Comment: Код чего, вопрос именно по сайту, ссылка на который есть в вопросе